# App Not Showing in Apps

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm debugging using my Samsung Galaxy S5 and every time I run it through Android Studio it works fine and it pops up the app, but then when I click out of it it doesn't show in all of my apps like other apps I've installed to my device. The app will show in my task manager after I close out of it but it still won't show in all of my apps. Really could use some help on this one, thanks.

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="us.bisonsoftware.tab" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Husky Athletics"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".TabBarExample"
        android:label="Husky Athletics"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <data android:scheme="geo"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".FirstTab" />
    <activity android:name=".SecondTab" />
    <activity android:name=".ThirdTab" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: uninstall app in your phone.

Comment: I already tried this and it didn't work.  Uninstalling it was what made it go away initially.

Comment: Does this happen on another device ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your activity name complete like this:

```
<activity
   android:name="com.example.myapp.TabBarExample"
   ... >
</activity>
```

I dont know your package name. You have to fill it by yourself.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. This is what I put in:     android:name="us.bisonsoftware.tab.TabBarExample"